Gmail api throws "HttpStatusCode is BadRequest. Precondition check failed." when authorizing with service account
So im trying to send an email with the gmail API in C# however i keep the following error when i try to send the email: "HttpStatusCode is BadRequest. Precondition check failed.". The service account has owner permissions.
Below is the code im using to send said email:
var credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile("service.json").CreateScoped(GmailService.Scope.GmailSend);
string htmlbody = File.ReadAllText("email templates/parenttemplate.html"); 
string message = $"To: {parent}\r\nSubject: {parentsubject}\r\nContent-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n<h1>{htmlbody}</h1>";
var service = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer() { HttpClientInitializer = credential, ApplicationName = ApplicationName });
var msg = new Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data.Message();
msg.Raw = Base64UrlEncode(message.ToString());
service.Users.Messages.Send(msg, "<The email of my service account>").Execute();

